# On solution to the equation $x_{1}^{2}x_{2}^{2}x_{3}^{2}x_{4}^{2}x_{5}^{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{6}a_{i}x_{i}\right)^{2}=1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

For any $a_{1}, a_{2}, \dots, a_{6} \in \mathbb{R}$ with

$$\sum_{i=1}^{6}a_{i}^{2}=1$$

is it true that there always exist $x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots, x_{6} \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{6}x_{i}^{2}=6$ such that

$$x_{1}^{2}x_{2}^{2}x_{3}^{2}x_{4}^{2}x_{5}^{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{6}a_{i}x_{i}\right)^{2}=1?
$$

Any helpful answer that could lead to a correct answer to this question
would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Let $f(x) = f(x_1, \ldots, x_6)$ be the value of the expression on the left side of the displayed equation. At one extreme, choose $x_i = \text{sign}(a_i) \in \{-1, 1\}$ for each $i$. Then surely $f(x) = M = \left(\sum_{i=1}^6 |a_i|\right)^2 \geq 1$ since $\sum_{i=1}^6 a_i^2 = 1$. At another extreme, $f(x) = 0$ as soon as $x_2 = 0$ say (e.g., $x = (\sqrt{6}, 0, \ldots, 0)$. Since $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^6| \sum_{i=1}^6 x_i^2 = 6\}$ is connected, its image under $f$ is connected and therefore contains every value in the interval $[0, M]$, including $1$ in particular.

Comment: Wasn't there a question very similar just a couple of days ago?

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
The answer is yes. Indeed, without loss of generality $a_i\ge0$ for all $i$. Let 
\begin{equation}
 S:=\Big\{(x_1,\dots, x_6)\in\R^6\colon\sum_{i=1}^6x_i^2=6\Big\}
\end{equation}
and let the function $f\colon S\to\R$ be defined by 
\begin{equation}
 f(x_1,\dots, x_6):=(x_1\cdots x_6)^2\Big(\sum_{i=1}^6a_ix_i\Big)^2. 
\end{equation}
Since $S$ is connected and $f$ is continuous, the set $f(S)$ is an interval in $\R$. Moreover, 
\begin{equation}
 0=f(0,\dots,0,\sqrt6)\in f(S)
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
 f(1,\dots,1)=\Big(\sum_{i=1}^6a_i\Big)^2\ge\sum_{i=1}^6a_i^2=1. 
\end{equation}
So, 
\begin{equation}
 1\in\big[f(0,\dots,0,\sqrt6),f(1,\dots,1)\big]\subseteq f(S). 
\end{equation}
That is, there is $(x_1,\dots, x_6)\in S$ such that $f(x_1,\dots, x_6)=1$, as desired.

Comment: I don't think your inequality is right: suppose the $a_i$'s cancel each other. Of course this is easily repaired, but maybe this question is too trivial for MO?

Comment: I see that, while I was typing this answer, Todd Trimble made a comment with essentially the same content.

Comment: @ToddTrimble : I had assumed, without loss of generality, that $a_i\ge0$ for all $i$, which will prevent the cancellation.

Comment: Oh you did; sorry.

Comment: This is the kind of argument that one learns in 1st year analysis courses.